# How to change the order of QTableView rows by dragging and store the changes to the model?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qsqlquerymodel

I want to know how to change the order of `QTableView` rows by dragging, and store the order changes to the model?

I use QTableView as view and QSqlTableModel as model. I am using Qt 5.15.

I set:

```cpp
ui->table_view->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->table_view->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->table_view->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Methods I tried:

1.

```cpp
ui->table_view->setSectionsMovable(true);
ui->table_view->setDragEnabled(true);
ui->table_view->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
ui->table_view->setAcceptDrops(true);
```

It doesn't take effect. The row cannot be dragged.

2.

```cpp
ui->table_view->verticalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
ui->table_view->verticalHeader()->setDragEnabled(true);
ui->table_view->verticalHeader()->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
ui->table_view->verticalHeader()->setAcceptDrops(true);
```

The row can be dragged by vertical header. But the order of changes will not affect the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the QTableView does not call moveRows method of the model by itself. Instead drag and drop actions call *mimeData methods.

So, one option would be the following:

In your model you need to implement `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` functions. When you drag and drop a row the view will ask for `mimeData()` of the given row. If you are sure that you need only internal moves you can encode the selected row indices to `QMimeData`. Then in the `dropMimeData()` you decode the indices that were selected and use them to call your `moveRows()` implementation. Return `false` from this function to prevent removing of the moved out rows.

Another option can be to override the QTableView methods such as `dropEvent()` in a way, that it calls the model `moveRows()` method directly.

Comment: Thank you. So I should subclassing the QSqlTableModel and implement these functions? Does QSqlTableModel not support this feature?

Comment: @Ginakira I think you should subclass it, but I am not aware of the QSqlTableModel details, this was a general idea for QAbstractTableModel